# RDP Wrapper not working Windows 10 home 10.0.19041.1081

Tags: linux, windows-10, remote-desktop

I recently found out that we cannot use remote desktop on windows 10 home. So I have downloaded RDP Wrapper, and everything seems to work fine (according to this screenshot): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WCbU.png)

But whenever I want to connect to my kali Linux Azure RDP, it doesn't work and shows up this error message: [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfBgF.png)

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You are positive there is a RDP server running on the Kali VM?

Comment: Fixed my probelm ! Actualy I can't connect to any rdp while using a free hotspot wifi, instead I need to use a private wifi.